# How to Map Contacts?

Tags: geocoding

When you open a Group and select Group members, you can run a "Map Contacts" Action (which, I suppose, would locate those members on a map).

But when I try, I get a message which tells me that the Contact Address does not contain Latitude/Longitude of the Contact.

I have tried to activate the "Geocode and Parse Address" CRON Job, but I get errors (last one : "A fatal error was triggered: Aborting batch geocoding. Hit the over query limit on geocoder.")

I did not find any detailed documentation about that.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally succeeded :

- Administer > Settings > Addresses > Address Editing with Latitude, Longitude, and Street Address Parsing enabled
- geocoding=1 and parse=0 in the Geocoding Parameters of the CRON job

Comment: Looks good - see also this answer https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16891/geocoding-in-the-uk

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the docs about mapping](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/mapping/) Not much there, and I've found that if you're using Google then you do need an API key in order to raise the limit on the amount of geo coding requests.  So in in Administer/System Settings/Mapping and Geocoding you can set the API key there.  To request a Google API key there's [info here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits)

Comment: Thank you Andy ; I read all that (also that you don't need an API key with Google, (except for numerous geocodings ?)) ; I finally tested a CRON job with geocoding=0, parse=1, start=1, end=100, throttle=0 : I get a message which tells me that it only works in the USA (???) (not in France) ; I really miss some detailled documentation.

Comment: I just tried to run geocoding on one of my sites & ran into the same problem.  Which reminded me how I fixed this in the past - by installing the OpenStreetMaps extension from Systopia - which is here https://civicrm.org/extensions/openstreetmap-geocoding  Although it only documents 4.6 it does work in 4.7

Comment: After installing the OpenStreetMaps extension on my test system, I had to enable street parsing for the batch job to run.  But the batch job did geocode several UK addresses and also geocodes UK addresses through the UI.  By the way, in the batch job I used geocoding=1, throttle=1

Comment: Thanks again Andy. Problem : I can't install openstreetmap extension : not listed in the Extension List (Add new), and if I download it from https://civicrm.org/extensions/openstreetmap-geocoding to my Extension Directory, it does not appear in my Extensions list (I am currently in 4.7.27)

Comment: Excuse the question, but did you unzip what you downloaded & then hit 'Refresh' in Civi?

Comment: Yes, I did ; I give up, because I found a way : see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Now that you’ve got Latitute and Longitude - you can also map your contacts this way: [How to put your CiviCRM Contacts on a Leafleft Map in 5min?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12862/how-to-put-your-civicrm-contacts-on-a-leafleft-map-in-5min)